# Apache httpd - how to figure which server is the request going to

Tags: apache, mod-jk

I am new to httpd. I have single Apache httpd server running, and is load balancing JBoss servers. Round robin, non-sticky bit configuration. I need to find out which of the JBoss servers is getting the request. I can't log to each JBoss servers, but, can log on to the httpd server.

How do I do that?

Thank you.

WM.

Comment: I am using mod_jk for load balancing..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can enable a status worker: http://tomcat.apache.org/connectors-doc/reference/status.html

You can monitor which worker's access count goes up, not ideal, but should do te trick.

Comment: Thank you "clmarquart". However, I am looking for more information. For example POST on search was directed to server1, POST on update to server2.

Comment: Thank you clmarquart. mod_jk, debug option helped. Appreciate it.